# After change to https ajax function don't work right

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, ssl

I'm using wordress and i wrote a small script to compare posts.
After i actived ssl it brokes my script.

I got this error in the developter consol.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>",
        data: {
                action: 'compare',
                post_id: $(checkbox).val(),
                _ajax_nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('compare'); ?>'
            },
        success: function(html){
                html = $.parseJSON(html);
                console.log('success');
                $('#count').fadeIn(200);
                $('#count').html(html.length);
        },
        error: function(html){
                 console.log('error');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
_ajax_nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('compare'); ?>'
```

to this:

```
_ajax_nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("compare"); ?>'
```

Comment: I change but after a click on the checkbox i got the same error message.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  . Before the change to ssl everything works perfect.

Comment: If you call the AJAX from an HTTPS page TO a non secure HTTP, then it violates JavaScript's same-origin policy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418620/jquery-ajax-and-ssl